# Page doesn't detect changes?

Tags: angular, ionic4

Good day, everyone. Please I’ve got a page that binds to a variable for content. But I’m noticing the page does not update when the variable changes. unless I navigate to another page and back before the changes reflect. Please I need your help. Thanks

**my edit page**
// am using ionic modal popup
// this page update user data

```
 async updateUserData(){

    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Updating...'
     });

     loading.present();
    this.isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');

    let customerDataUpdated = {
      "first_name": `${this.user.first_name}`,
      "last_name": `${this.user.last_name}`,
      "email": `${this.user.email}`,
      "username": `${this.user.username}`,
      "billing": {

        "address_1": `${this.user.billing.address_1}`,
       "phone": `${this.user.billing.phone}`
      },
    }


   console.log('new update', this.user);  

   //update user data

   this.WC.updateCustomerData(this.isUserLoggedIn, customerDataUpdated).then((data)=>{


    this.changedetector.detectChanges();
    loading.dismiss();  

          setTimeout(()=>{
          this.modalCtrl.dismiss({
            'dismissed': true
          });
      }, 3000);       

     });
```

**profile page**

```
// update on edit page does not reflect here unless I navigate to another tab and back

      constructor(private changedetector: ChangeDetectorRef, private WC: WoocommerceService,) {

    // this retrieve user data from api call    
         ngOnInit() {

   this.isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');
    this.WC.getUserInfo(this.isUserLoggedIn).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.customerData = data;  
    });


    this.WC.profileSubjects.subscribe((data) => {
 //    this.customerData = data;
     console.log('change update ', data);
  });
```

**woocommerce.service.ts**

```
    //getting authenticated users details from woocommerce

    getUserInfo(id){
      this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${id}?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
      console.log('API url for retrive customer: ', this.apiUrl);
      this.customerData = this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe( retry(1),catchError(this.handleError) );
      return this.customerData;
    }


    // this update user data
        updateCustomerData(id, customerDataUpdated){
          let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
          });
          this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${id}?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
         // console.log('API url for retrive customer data: ', this.apiUrl);
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.put(this.apiUrl, customerDataUpdated, {headers} ).subscribe(
              response => {
                resolve(response);
                console.log('Customer Data Updated: ', response);
            },
            error => {
              resolve(error);
             console.log('Customer Data Updated failed ', error);
            }
            )
          });
        }


updateCustomerData(id, customerDataUpdated){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  });
  this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${id}?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
 // console.log('API url for retrive customer data: ', this.apiUrl);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.put(this.apiUrl, customerDataUpdated, {headers} ).subscribe(
      response => {
        resolve(response);

        console.log('Customer Data Updated: ', response);
    },
    error => {
      resolve(error);
     console.log('Customer Data Updated failed ', error);
    }
    )
  });
```

Comment: 'getUserInfo()' looks like a method that gets called once when the constructor fires, not an eventEmitter or Subject that is being monitored. Can you include the WooCommerceService code?

Comment: I have included the WooCommerceService code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your method in the constructor of the page is only firing once when the class is first constructed i.e. page load, which is why you need to do a reload to make it fire again.

What you need to do is use a Subject and store data in it in the service and then subscribe to it in the profile page.

WooCommerceService code:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'; 

let profileSubject = new Subject<any>();

getUserInfo(id){
  this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${id}? 
    consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
    console.log('API url for retrive customer: ', this.apiUrl);
    this.customerData = this.http.get(this.apiUrl);

    // STORE WHATEVER DATA YOU WANT IN THE SUBJECT 
    this.profileSubject.next(this.customerData)
 .pipe(retry(1),catchError(this.handleError) );
   return this.customerData;
}

Profile page:

ngOnInit() {
     this.wc.profileSubject.subscribe(data => {
        // do something with the data
     }
}
```

Now, using the Subject method, anything that subscribes to the profileSubject will get updated data as it becomes available i.e. you call getUserInfo from anywhere in the app and the new data is pushed to anything that has subscribed.

There is also the BehaviorSubject which acts almost exactly the same but always has the last piece of data available, so a new subscriber always receives something at the time it subscribes instead of having to wait. It may be useful.

Also, keep the constructor lean, most code that you want to fire at page load should go in the ngOnInit to make sure that everything is available by the time the code tries to access it. This isn't guaranteed in the constructor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am sorry for responding late I just got your answer now. I have tried it out but I am still having the same issue, this is how I subscribe to it                                                                ngOnInit() {

    let isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');
    this.WC.getUserInfo(isUserLoggedIn).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.customerData = data;  
    });

    this.WC.profileSubject.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('change detected', data)
   });
   
   
  }

Comment: I don't see much in the way of changes, in particular I don't see a Subject being used. Try reading this tutorial, it may help: https://blog.angulartraining.com/rxjs-subjects-a-tutorial-4dcce0e9637f